# Need a regex for URL check?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, gcloud

I need a regex for a URL string.

My URL string goes like

https colon // string dot string / string (It does not contain any space in between)

Comment: Why? Google BigQuery supports [URL Datatype](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/URL-Data-Type_57344793) which makes it make more easy to check if something is a valid URL..

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I am planning to perform sentiment analysis on twitter data and in text I have these http links which needs to be removed for performing NLP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://gist.github.com/jacksonfdam/3000275
I found :

```
^http(s)?:\/\/((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)|(([\w-]+\.)+([a-z,A-Z][\w-]*)))(:[1-9][0-9]*)?(\/([\w-.\/:%+@&=]+[\w- .\/?:%+@&=]*)?)?(#(.*))?$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'check this link http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2' tweet UNION ALL
  SELECT 'http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2 this link is awesome' tweet UNION ALL
  SELECT 'the link http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2 is awesome' tweet 

)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tweet, r"(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+", '') clean_tweet
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row clean_tweet  
1   check this link  
2   this link is awesome     
3   the link is awesome
```

Comment: i wonder if using a delivered table which uses LIKE or CONTAINS to search for http and https first before running the regex engine would improve performance as you run the regex engine on a possible smaller resultset.. Maybe iám thinking to much full text index here which iam not sure off that Google BigQuery supports?

Comment: you can post your answer implementing this idea - so it will be more clear what exactly you have in mind. meantime, I feel the focus of this question is more detecting url - how exactly then it will be embed into specific use-case is up to OP or subject of another question

Comment: To tell you to the truth mine experience in Google BigQuery is exactly 0% the sql tag once drove me here, it was more a general idea.. As most of the time (full) regex engines can be pretty resource hungry.

Comment: you can try :o)